# How to change hostname via kernel command line on ubuntu 12

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, gentoo, upstart

I booted a guest vm on xen, and I want to assign guest-domU's hostname in config file. 
like this

```
...
extra='ip=::::myguest-vm-hostname::dhcp'
...
```

It is a kernel command line to setting netboot networking environment.

---

It works fine on gentoo. Some codes in the file `/etc/init.d/hostname` are

```
start(){
  hostname=${hostname-${HOSTNAME-localhost}}
  hostname $hostname
}
```

That will assign netboot hostname into real hostname.

---

But!
on ubuntu 12, the script `/etc/init/hostname.conf`(upstart) only get the `hostname` value in `/etc/hostname`, or it will be none...

I've tried that edit the /etc/init/hostname.conf on ubuntu like

```
exec hostname=${hostname-${HOSTNAME-localhost}}
exec hostname "$hostname"
```

but it doesn't work...

Any help will be appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I come here to answer my question...
I should not erase all contents in /etc/init/hostname.conf(ubuntu), and write the same code of /etc/init.d/hostname(gentoo) into it.
the original /etc/init/hostname.conf
is

```
task
exec hostname -b -F /etc/hostname
```

the workable hostname.conf is

```
task
export hostname=${hostname-${HOSTNAME-localhost}}
exec hostname $hostname
```

On Ubuntu, I should not direct assign variable like `hostname=xxx`, and I should prepend `export` to it.

It looks really stupid... haha.